# unable to format the xaxis using scales package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data and trying to use ggplot2 and scales to format the xaxis, having date and time.

```
dput(head(pp))
structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1362405600, 1362409200, 
1362412800, 1362416400, 1363006800, 1363010400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Day = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed"
), class = "factor"), Total_Logins = c(818832L, 801771L, 787508L, 
731672L, 748872L, 727140L), Unique_Logins = c(732152L, 713380L, 
701348L, 647321L, 672848L, 649453L), Date = structure(c(15768, 
15768, 15768, 15768, 15775, 15775), class = "Date")), .Names = c("DateTime", 
"Day", "Total_Logins", "Unique_Logins", "Date"), row.names = c(1498L, 
1499L, 1500L, 1501L, 1666L, 1667L), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(subset(pp, Day=="Fri"), aes(DateTime, Total_Logins, group=1)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_smooth(method="loess", se=T, size=1) + 
    scale_x_date(breaks = "1 day", labels=date_format("%b-%d-%Y %H"))
```

I get this error:

> Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

My DateTime column is Date formated already. Any ideas, what I am doing here wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As column `DateTime` contains date with time together (class POSIXct) and you also want to show hour for x axis labels you should use `scale_x_datetime()` instead of `scale_x_date()`.

```
+scale_x_datetime(breaks = "1 day", labels=date_format("%b-%d-%Y %H"))
```

To change breaks at which x axis ticks are shown you can change `breaks="1 day"` to, for example, to `breaks="6 hours"`. Another possibility is to show breaks only where actual values are available. If there are too many axis text items then you can change direction of texts.

```
+scale_x_datetime(breaks = unique(pp$DateTime), labels=date_format("%b-%d-%Y %H"))+
        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,vjust=0.5))
```

Comment: I am using this I am still having some sort of issues. I have data for 9, 10, 11, 12 hours. I need to show this by date and time in the xaxis. that I use the above scale_x_datetime, I only get all 00 for the hour. I need to show the time that I have the data points.

Comment: @user1471980 Then you have to decide how offen you want to see your values - if regularly then use breaks=".. hours", if unregularly then provide your own breaks.

Comment: I need to show data points for 9, 10, 11, 12 for each date on the data frame.

Comment: as the above graph shows, data points are vertical. it should not be vertical.

Comment: @user1471980 They are not vertical - try to stretch your plot wider and you will see that they are not vertical. If your data are only for some hours then that's the way you see them. Maybe you can convert time to factor (that will eliminate space between points from two dates) but that won't be the best way.

Comment: converting Date to factor accomplished my task, thank you so much.